# Ajax checking if file exists on server not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$imageURL = "/root/development/servers/account_" + $accountID + "/social_" + $socialCount + "/bots/" + $botName + "_" + ($id + 1) + ".png";
$.ajax ({
    url: $imageURL,
    success: function() {
        alert("1");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("0");
    }
});
```

This is the code I am using, it always alerts 0 even though my file exists (I display the full path in a text field and alerted it to check). Everything I find on google says this is the way to do it, are those outdated? Do I have to give specific permissions to allow the file to be seen? What could be going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: It's may be path related problem. Check your browser console/network tab for error

Comment: The URL in `$imageURL` is absolute, not relative. @AnikIslamAbhi

Comment: Off-topic: it is highly recommended not to use `success` and `error`. Moreover, it is deprecated since jQuery 3.0. Use `.done()` and `fail()`

Comment: What do you get in the network tab?

Comment: I'm almost sure `$. ajax` call expects a string to be returned from the request and not an image... Therefore an image will cause the error function to fire.

Comment: @Dekel you are right, no data returned, but he want to check if url exist or not, then IMHO is better use http status codes for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this java script image function:

```
var image = new Image(); 
image.src = $imageURL;
if (image.width == 0) {
  alert("no image");
}
```

or try this one too:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: $imageURL,
    type: "HEAD",
    success: function() {
        alert("1");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("0");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below function :

common function for check the file exists on server :

```
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

and put your request like below:

```
$.get(image_url)
    .done(function() { 
        // Do something now you know the image exists.

    }).fail(function() { 
        // Image doesn't exist - do something else.

    })
```

Hope it helps you..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution with status code which request return.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png',
    statusCode: {
        200: function() {
            alert( "image found" );
        },
        404: function() {
            alert( "image not found" );
        }
    }
});
```